# React state value won't update

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update state and set `preview` value to undefined, but it's not working.

here is my code

```
console.log(preview);
this.setState({ preview }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.preview);
});
```

I try to put something else in preview, but still it's not working.

```
undefined
Object { ... }
```

other value in state is working, just this one it's not working.

**UPDATE**
another weird thing is that when I update another value it will be updated.

for example

```
this.setState({preview:undefined,media:undefined});
```

the media will updated to undefined, but `preview` will not.

Comment: *What* isn't working? Please be more specific. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DrewReese I'm trying to update my state, look at log, the first one is undefined, and the second one ( after updating state)  has value

Comment: What is the second snippet?  Is the `undefined` the first log or the second log of `this.state.preview`? What is the object? Does it relate to preview at all? Is anything else in your code also setting preview state? We need more context.

Comment: @DrewReese I update my code, the object vlaue is `Object { id: "387709", title: "q1 (2).jpg", filesize: "1116694", date: "2020-04-14 07:33:10", fileType: "image", ext: "jpg" }`

Comment: @AliAkbarAzizi what is type of `state.preview` ?

Comment: it has no type. i don't use react prop type

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but with so little code and context it's unlikely we'll resolve this issue. Also, types are a part of vanilla javascript. Please update your question with more context and clearer detail around what current value of `preview` is, what you are setting it to, what the relevance of the second snippet is, etc...

Comment: @DrewReese I don't know which part of code is important, my class is about 800 line. Also update my question

Comment: React state updates are asynchronous and batched processed for the next render/commit cycle. What this means then is if *any other part of the code* also is setting state of `preview` to some value after the update you shared, your update is lost. [demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/prod-sunset-lgmw3?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark)

Comment: @DrewReese if you write it as an answer, I will accepted that, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React state updates are asynchronous and batched processed for the next render/commit cycle. What this means then is if any other part of the code also is setting *the same* state to some value after *an* update, *that* update is lost.

Demo

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value: "test"
  };

  updateState = () => {
    this.setState({ value: undefined }, () =>
      console.log("value", this.state.value) // logs "test2"!!
    );
    this.setState({ value: "test2" });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>state: {this.state.value}</div>

        <button type="button" onClick={this.updateState}>
          Update state
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit lost state update]